# Infer common super-type

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference

Here is what I am trying to do

```
  def merge[A, B, C](eithers: Either[A,B]*)(implicit ev1: A <:< C, ev2: B <:< C): Seq[C] =
     eithers.flatMap(_.fold(Option[C](_), Option[C](_)))
```

Basically, I want to "flatten" a list of `Either[A,B]` into a `Seq[C]`, where C is the common super-type of A, and B (other than `Any`, obviously).

For example:

```
  trait Foo
  class Bar extends Foo
  class Baz extends Foo

  merge(Left[Bar, Baz](new Bar), Right[Bar, Baz](new Baz))
```

This does not work :( 
It says `Cannot prove that Baz <:< C`

This, however, does work:

```
  merge[Bar, Baz, Foo](Left[Bar, Baz](new Bar), Right[Bar, Baz](new Baz))
  res7: Seq[Foo] = ArrayBuffer(Bar@613f7eb7, Baz@565aa4ac)
```

So, the question is can someone thing of some sort of trick to make it infer to common super-type, so that I don't have to spell it out like this? 
Or, at least, a way to do this with only one type parameter (I don't mind specifying the type of the result as much, as I do having to spell out the types of the incoming data).

One way I know to do the latter is assign it to a variable:

```
val merged: Seq[Foo] = merge(Left[Bar, Baz](new Bar), Right[Bar, Baz](new Baz))
```

This works, but doesn't quite cut it for me, because I hate declaring variables, that are only used once. Ideally, I am looking to do something like this:

```
merge(input)
  .filter(doILikeIt)
  .map(doSomethingInteresting)
// etc.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use the fact that `Either[A, B] extends Either[C, C]`, because of variance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple solution, using variance:

```
def merge[C](eithers: Either[C, C]*): Seq[C] = eithers.map(_.fold(x => x, x => x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using type bounds instead of implicit parameters works for me:

```
def merge[A <: C, B <: C, C](eithers: Either[A,B]*): Seq[C] =
  eithers.flatMap(_.fold(Option[C](_), Option[C](_)))
```